# scss в css (vs code)

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code, scss

Верстаю сайт (html, scss css), столкнулся с такой проблемой: при записи scss и последующей компиляции в css не учитывается отношение между родительским и дочерним элементом. После просмотра документации на сайте/ютуб/статьях на форумах и попытке редактировать настройки изменений не произошло. Пример даю на скриншоте. Установлены расширения: scss formatter, scss intellisense, live sass compiler, html to css scss less, acsstractor, autoprefixer[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Скажите пожалуйста, находится ли моя ошибка в настройках текстового редактора или в возможностях языка? Как корректно настроить эту функцию дабы сразу переводить в css, а так же как быстро копировать классы с html для scss? Буду рад любому совету, ссылке на ресурс или подсказке где еще я могу найти материал для решения проблемы. Всем спасибо!

(символ родителя менял несколько раз как в левой части так и в правой, ничего не происходит)

Comment: я работаю без расширений в терминале вбиваю команду sass --watch src/sass:src/css (sass --watch местоположение sass: местоположение css)и все

Comment: Так а что не работает?

Comment: - Так а что не работает?
- Имею ввиду, что когда просматриваешь css файл, то неверно записан дочерний класс, то есть "перевод" не делается (белым светится). Хочу узнать как правильно переводить scss в css, вот в чем дело.

Comment: Все сделано правильно. Просто вам нужно задать для `header` какой-то класс (допустим `.header`) и уже с ним работать в scss.

Comment: У Вас ошибка в SCSS коде... Так как родитель у Вас `header`, а ниже Вы пишете `&__container`, то результатом будет `header__container`. [Parent Selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector/)

Comment: как указал сверху - для копирования классов я использовал расширение (html converter to scss/less/css), сейчас попробую узнать, может в этом корень проблемы. Заранее всем спасибо за предыдущие ответы.